# App insights : can't extract my app ID using instrumentation key

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

in my .NET core project i'm trying to extract my AppId using the intrumentation key from my app insights : 
   TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = _configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];

```
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ApplicationIdProvider = new ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider()
            {
                ProfileQueryEndpoint = "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/api/profiles/{0}/appId"
            };
            bool isSuccessRetrieve = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ApplicationIdProvider.TryGetApplicationId(_configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"], out string applicationId);
```

However the result is always false and appID is null as if my app insights doesn't exist.

Is there some configurations that i missed ? do anyone know why ?

Comment: try `_configuration["ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey"]`

Comment: _configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"] actually returns me the string that contains my InstrumentationKey in the appsettings.json so the problem is not in _configuration, it is rather in the TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ApplicationIdProvider.TryGetApplicationId() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this manually :

```
private bool TryGetApplicationId(string intrumentationKey, out string appId)
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://dc.services.visualstudio.com");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Format("api/profiles/{0}/appId", intrumentationKey), Method.GET);
            RestResponse response = (RestResponse) restClient.Execute(request);
            appId = response.Content;
            return response.IsSuccessful;
        }
```

Comment: can you please share the RestClient code or it's assembly?

Comment: It's an assembly that you can find on NUGET. just type "RestSharp" and install it in your project

Comment: thank you very much, you can mark it as answer and it do help others.

Comment: This definitely works - but I can't find this API documented anywhere. Where did you find it?